# How to transfer Right-to-Left text from Excel to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, excel, migration

I have a collection of data in my Excel which the language is [right-to-Left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left). My data collection is very large. I want to transfer this to my SQL Server database and insert the values into a table.

For example it would be like this:

```
Insert City (Id, City, State_Id)
values (1, N'right-to-left text', 5)
```

Right-to-Left sample :    `(2, N'تهران')`

As you might be aware the prefix `N` is used to describe the character.

My question is how would I be able to transfer all this data without having to overwrite them again?

The main problem is the right-to-left characters

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, are you asking how to use Excel as a source for the insert or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, yes!
The language in my data source is Persian (right-to-left) If I want to insert it into SQL Server with the same format(right-to-left) I have to use the prefix N(' ') and I don't want to overwrite this
 N(' ') for all data because the record is too much
I hope I was clear

Comment: "right-to-left" or "left-to-right" in terms of the language that is used doesn't make any difference for SQL Server as long as you use the proper collation for the column and insert the data as unicode.

Comment: It does, If I insert the data without N'', it will show question marks because it can not recognize the character (Unicode Problem).
 
An nvarchar column can store any Unicode data.You may have seen Transact-SQL code that passes strings around using an N prefix. This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (the N actually stands for National language character set). Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as opposed to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT.

Comment: What are you using to transfer the data? Sql Server DTS, or Excel Import/Export, ADO.NET or something else?

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER DTS, I wonder if there is any program or a query that can take care of this.

Comment: I don't know of any tool. But this should be easy. Save your Excel file as `Unicode Text` (*File > Save As > Unicode Text(*.txt)*). Then use DTS to transfer from this file, or use the BCP utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to perform this:

1. Right click on Database -> Task -> Import Data -> Select Excel as your data source ->     continue until the wizard is finished .
2. The longgest way:

   - In Excel add the following Columns before your data as follow:

[image]

- Copy and paste your data set in a new query on SQL Server.

  Use Ctrl + H to replace the blank spots like follow:

[image]

format it as you like and you're good to go!